# Substitute subsystem name into udev string

Tags: udev

Is there a way to substitute the subsystem name into a string in a udev rule (udev version 215)?

For example (this does not work):

```
ACTION=="add", ENV{COMMENT}="subsystem is $subsystem"
```

I tried `$subsystem` and `$SUBSYSTEM` (like `$kernel` and `$name`) but neither of those work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the manual, under *rule and device options* >> *available substitutions*:

```
   $env{key}, %E{key}
       A device property value.
```

so in your case it should be either

```
ENV{COMMENT}="subsystem is $env{SUBSYSTEM}"
```

or

```
ENV{COMMENT}="subsystem is %E{SUBSYSTEM}"
```

As noted, the key name must be in caps.

Comment: Ah, so that's what it meant by "device property". Incidentally, `$env{ACTION}` works to get the action too. Awesome, thank you!

Comment: @JasonC - yeah man, if you read the man page it says: _The following key names can be used to match against device properties..._ and you have there the list of all available key names along with a short description...